# Confusion with First order Propositional Logic clause

Tags: logic, clause, first-order-logic

I have two propositions `p` and `q`. So is it legal to write the clause as:
`q ∧ p ∧ ¬ p`
I am assuming that, in this case 
`p ∧ ¬ p = F`
will always be False, hence the clause will become
`q ∧ F = F`
resulting the whole clause as False.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I had confusion whether that clause `q ∧ p ∧ ¬ p' is valid or not !!

Comment: The clause is [well formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula), that's different from [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity), which isn't really what you're thinking of since there is no inference, or since you haven't considered models or semantics. Best.

Comment: @Tom...so, you are saying, the clause is valid but not sound!!

Comment: Er, no. I'm saying the clause is well formed, in the language. I don't understand the way you are using the term validity here- what definition did you have in mind?